# Is not using models.*Field for variables in models allowed?

Tags: django, variables, django-models

If you have a model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
  variable_name = value
  variable_name2 = models.FieldType(default=value)
```

what's the difference; is the first one allowed? What kind of variable is that?

```
i.e count = 2 vs count = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

**Follow Up Question**

I know this is inherently what goes against constant variables but is there a variable that will be shared among all instances but is still editable?

Static/Constant variables seem to be shared among all instances but by definition it seems it must be defined in the code; instead of by User Input which is what I want.

class Dog(models.Model):
 var = 10; # this is the static variable, but you want this to be changeable in admin

instance = Dog(____) # will get var = 10

Comment: `models.*Field` get saved in the db. Other things don't. You're allowed to do it, but honestly, unless it's a constant of some sort, expect odd behavior.

Comment: Isn't it just considered a static/constant variable shared among all instances? Just tested if it is saved in the db and it seems to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NightShadeQueen said, the models.*Field fields are saved to the database. The other is a constant.

As for your second question, no there is not. It is a constant and while you can change it, it will only remain changed for the scope of the instance. Here's an example of what it would mean:

```
class Example(models.Model):
  variable_name = 5

def description():
    instance_a = Example()
    instance_a.variable_name == 5  # True
    instance_a.variable_name = 'hello'
    instance_a.variable_name == 'hello'  # True
    instance_b = Example()
    instance_b.variable_name == instance_a.variable_name  # False
    instance_b.variable_name == 5  # True
```

The best thing you could do is to create a singleton model to house those global variables you want re-used for every user.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with the singleton model solution?

Comment: A model that doesn't allow for more than one instance of it.

Comment: Ah thank you, I guess I need to find another alternative to what I'm looking for because that is the opposite I think.